# Another one lost at ModuleNotFoundError with pytest

Tags: python, pytest, modulenotfounderror

I've read so many posts about pytest and ModuleNotFoundError and tried all the advices I've found so far. Now I feel totally lost. So I hope someone can help me out getting the correct answer.

This is my project structure trying to follow [good practice](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html):

```
myproject/
  pyproject.toml #(with [tool.pytest.ini_options] / pythonpath = ["src"])
  setup.py
  setup.cfg #(with [options] / include_package_data = True / package_dir=src / packages=find:)
  src/
     conftest.py #(tried with and without this empty file)
     myproject/
        __init__.py
        myproject.py
        ui/
          __init__.py
          ui_main.py
          ui_div.py
        scripts/
          __init__.py
          calculations.py # with: from config import constants
        config/
          __init__.py
          constants.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_calculation.py # trying to: from scripts import calculations
```

The application is running and imports are working.
Then when trying to test with pytest the methods in `calculations.py` I struggle with the imports.

```py
# test_calculation.py
from scripts import calculations
```

and it fails on `ModuleNotFoundError` of `scripts`. I have also tried to set

```py
from src.myproject.scripts import calculations
```

This remove the `ModulNotFoundError` of 'scripts' (if running `python -m pytest`), but just stops at another `ModuleNotFoundError` of `config` when trying to import `config.constants` in `calculations.py`. Then I'm stuck again.

I have a virtual environment and am at the project top-level folder. I am using Anaconda with CMD prompt using `python -m pytest`.
pytest is uninstalled in (base) and installed in (venv).

I have run `pip install -e .`

I have deactivated/activated (venv) after installing pytest.

I have tried with and without this in `tests/__init__.py`.

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../src/myproject')))
```

and without /myproject.

I have tried the different settings indicated as comments in the folder structure above.

Maybe some combination of all this would work, but now I'm so fed up from hours of testing and failing realizing that I really do not understand this. Also the the posts I'm reading with 'just do this' and 'just do that' and it works for some and not for others... Any help on where I've got lost?

I guess I could move the tests folder at the same level as the other modules to make it work, but I'd like to use the recommended project layout to leave the tests out when distributing my real project.

Answer (score 1):

With this layout:

```
myproject/
├── pyproject.toml
├── src
│   └── myproject
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── scripts
│           └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── test_scripts.py
```

And this `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = "src"
```

And this content in `tests/test_scripts.py`:

```
import myproject.scripts


def test_myfunction():
    res = myproject.scripts.myfunction()
    assert res == "foo"
```

And this content in `src/myproject/scripts/__init__.py`:

```
def myfunction():
    return "foo"
```

I can run `pytest` from the top-level `myproject` directory and it is able to find and successfully run the tests:

```
$ pwd
.../myproject
$ ls
pyproject.toml
src
tests
$ pytest
========================================== test session starts ==========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.7, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/lars/tmp/python/myproject, configfile: pyproject.toml
collected 1 item

tests/test_scripts.py .                                                                           [100%]

=========================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ===========================================
```

---

In your question, this...

```
from scripts import calculations
```

...fails because you don't have a package named `scripts`. You have a package named `myproject` that includes a module named `mypackage.scripts`.

In general you should never have to modify `sys.path`.

---

In the above configuration, we're using `pyproject.toml` to set the root of your package via the `pythonpath` option. Alternatively, we can drop that section from `pyproject.toml` and instead create an empty file `src/conftest.py`.

Pytest uses that `conftest.py` to identify the root of your Python packages.

That layout looks like:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── myproject
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── scripts
│           └── __init__.py
└── tests
    └── test_scripts.py
```

---

**Update**

Your problem with `from config import constants` in `myproject.scripts.calculations` is -- again -- that you don't have a package named `config`. You have a package named `myproject`, that contains a `config` module. So you need:

```
from myproject.config import constants
```

Or, if you prefer relative imports:

```
from ..config import constants
```

(I would stick with absolute imports.)

So if we have `src/myproject/scripts/calcluations.py` with this content:

```
from myproject.config import constants

def myfunction():
    return constants.COLOR
```

And `src/myproject/config/constants.py` with this content:

```
COLOR = "blue"
```

Giving us this layout:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── myproject
│       ├── config
│       │   ├── constants.py
│       │   └── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── scripts
│           ├── calculations.py
│           └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_scripts.py
```

And we update `tests/test_scripts.py` to look like this:

```
import myproject.scripts.calculations


def test_myfunction():
    res = myproject.scripts.calculations.myfunction()
    assert res == "blue"
```

Everything continues to work.

---

> I am still confused because If I change the calculations.py to have 'from myproject.config import constants' I get a ModuleNotFoundError when running the application from myproject.py.

You wouldn't run things "from `myproject.py`". Given your layout, you can do this:

```
$ cd src
$ python
>>> import myproject.myproject
```

Or similarly:

```
cd src
python -m myproject.myproject
```

Comment: Yes, as I tried to explain above the ModuleNotFoundError for 'scripts' are solved by import myproject.scripts or import src.myproject.scripts, but then, as calculations.py contain import from other modules (config) I get the next ModuleNotFoundError when calculation.py is trying to import config.

Comment: See my update: you're continuing to try to import things with the wrong package name. I've put all the files from this answer [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-74159246) if that helps.

Comment: I am still confused because If I change the calculations.py to have 'from myproject.config import constants' I get a ModuleNotFoundError when running the application from myproject.py. So then pytest work, but not the application. (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject.config'; 'myproject' is not a package)

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect your latest comment. (and I've updated the example repository).

Comment: I have been running myproject.py from within Spyder in debug mode and from command line from within folder \src\myproject. Both these have been working fine except for the pytest part. When adding 'myproject.' before the modules when importing I succeed running myproject.myproject from the outer project folder, but debug in Spyder fails with ModuleNotFound.  Also pytest seem to not finding any test files now (collected 0 items).

Comment: "have been running myproject.py from within Spyder in debug mode and from command line from within folder \src\myproject." Don't do that; that's not how Python packages work. I've done my best to present the canonical solution here. I've invested a chunk of time trying to address your original question and your updates; if you don't like this answer you are welcome to work out a different solution.

Comment: I really apprechiate your answers! and you spending your time to help me. It is not that I do not like your answers. I have tried to implement it into my code, but have not succeeded in making it work for both debugging in Spyder and pytest. I fully understand if you give up on me. I am trying to understand why your code succeed in pytest, but mine do not after implementing the changes you have suggested. And I hope to continue using Spyder for debugging without having to change a lot of import statements when switching between pytest and Spyder debug mode.

Comment: @EllenWasbo the issue is that you cannot set up spyder to run from a directory other than the root and then expect both spyder and conventional python packaging and pytest to work. You should set up spider to run from the same root dir so that imports work the same way. Larsks set up the package and testing correctly in this answer. You should set it up this way too, and then figure out how to set up spider to work with this (correct) structure, not the other way around. Good luck! This stuff is legitimately hard to get used to but once you’ve done it a few times you get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelDelgado for wishing me luck and confirming that this stuff is a bit hard to get used to and to understand. I think I am getting the hang of this now, changing some strategies on how to debug and using the project and comments from larsks as a guideline for "the right way". I see now that it fits better in with all the other fragments of python info I find on the wide web.

Comment: for sure! also - there are a few different conventions on to do this, so that makes it even more confusing. I usually put `myproject` in the root dir so that running your python session from the root dir works the same way as when you deploy the package, e.g.  with `pip install`. but I've seen articles suggesting the way you have it, with the package under `src`, is preferable. but you may need to run spider/python from within src... I'm actually not sure.